# list is not appending but its overwriting

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, list, radgrid

Can anyone tell me why when I click the new button that my list fills with getapprials is being wiped out by line 184. The paste bin link below adds the new record to this list that is declared at the top.

//  private List apprList;
        BindingList apprList;

http://pastebin.com/f1SJxtay

**My binding source in the screen is the following:**

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource =  pamsContext.GetAppraisals(empNo);
grvappraisal.DataSource = bs;
```

**The following paste bin shows this:**

```
public List<AppraisalList> GetAppraisals(int empno)
{
    List<AppraisalList> appraisal = new List<AppraisalList>();

    try
    {
        var q = from appr in pamsEntities.appraisals
                where (appr.emp_no == empno)
                select new
                {
                    Contract_id=appr.contract_id,
                    EmployeeId=appr.emp_no,
                    Career_Id =appr.career_id,
                    Appraisal_Date=appr.appraisal_date,
                    appraised_by = appr.appraised_by,
                    Next_Date=appr.next_date,
                    Rating=appr.rating,
                    notes = appr.notes,
                    Submitted = appr.submitted,
                    Readiness = appr.Readiness,
                    Talentrating = appr.TalentRating,
                    Performancescore = appr.PerformanceScore
                };

        if (q != null)
        {
            Array.ForEach(q.ToArray(), appr =>
            {

                appraisal.Add(new AppraisalList(
                    appr.EmployeeId, 
                    0, 
                    appr.Contract_id, 
                    Convert.ToDateTime("15/08/2013"),
                    appr.appraised_by, 
                    Convert.ToDateTime("15/08/2013"), 
                    90, 
                    "test", 
                    Convert.ToDateTime("15/08/2013"), 
                    1, 
                    2, 
                    3));
            });
        }
        return appraisal;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new EntityContextException("GetAppraisals failed.", ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: try appraisal.AddRange(new AppraisalList(appr.EmployeeId, 0, appr.Contract_id, Convert.ToDateTime("15/08/2013"),appr.appraised_by, Convert.ToDateTime("15/08/2013"), 90, "test", Convert.ToDateTime("15/08/2013"), 1, 2, 3));

Comment: @Nisarg Shah would this be in the getappraissals sub routine nisarg

Comment: nope that didnt work im afarid i need to no what more to do on the cmd new button have a look at the past bin i put up plz

Comment: Can you provide with downloadable code? or sample code with same issue

Comment: their was a paste bin in the orignal post

http://pastebin.com/f1SJxtay

Comment: http://pastebin.com/f1SJxtay its in the paste bin

Comment: @NisargShah http://pastebin.com/f1SJxtay

Comment: To make this easier to debug I'd split the line 184 into: var newItem = new AppraisalList(empNo, contractId, contractId, Convert.ToDateTime("15/08/2013"), "david", Convert.ToDateTime("15/08/2013"), 90, "test", Convert.ToDateTime("15/08/2013"), 1, 2, 3);

apprList.Add(newItem); At least then you can make sure the new object looks ok.

Comment: thanks @damon i think i need to store whats im getting from getapriasl to new list but i thought i was doing that in the subroutine

Comment: @Damon how would i save the changes back to the database if its a normal list

Comment: Have you fixed the problem with the add now? I think you just need to call SaveChanges on PamsContext to save it (in you save method). Have you tried this?

Comment: @Damon have tried this but its not saving out the changes to the list do i need to do an add object ill post a paste bin in this http://pastebin.com/tv1t77W3 you will see in my code savechanges in caled on delete button event handler

Comment: i meen its not saving the changins out to the db

Comment: That is because you might not be having primary key in the table. Check for it in the table

Comment: their is http://pastebin.com/TRCG9HzH  @NisargShah

Comment: Did you tried using SQL Profiler? You should be able to track your query there and then decide if the query being generated and executed on SQL is correct or not

Comment: we just using sql 2008 express doe it have it @Nisarg Shah

Comment: Don't know for sure. But you can download SQL profiler so that any transactions that is executed on server can be captured there.

Comment: Looking at it again, I think you need to let the Data Context know that you've added a new item, check out this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx. In your cmdnew_click method, try adding PamsContext.appraisal.Add(newItem) before rebinding the list (I think appraisal is your object but just check what intellisense comes up with.

Comment: i have tried but when i pased the list to the .add it throws an errro that it cant complile

Comment: AddApprisal(appraisal appraisalsdata)
        {
            try
            {
                
                pamsEntities.AddToappraisals(appraisalsdata);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new EntityContextException("AddApprisal failed.", ex);
            }

this is what my addtoaprisals has

Comment: @Damon im using visual studio 2012 if makes a diff

Comment: VS 2012 isn't going to make a difference in this case and there won't be a AddToappraisals method either. In the PamsContext have a look for the object you are trying to add a record to, this should then have an Add method. The code I pasted earlier probably won't compile because I'm just making assumptions based on the code I can see. Read the link I sent you, there's some good examples in there about adding new items.

Comment: @Damon i got it working no worries i was using the list as the pirmary source duh me lol instead of the entity one question though in ef how do i pass a null string in when the coulmn is not null is their anywaay of doing this ? creating a new record but the field appraised by will be typed in